# how to turn/flip/curl image in android

Tags: android, animation

i have like a 100 images in my assets folder and i want to be able to curl them with the finger (no button) to make the app more dynamic. Is there an animation that lets me do this? Im also wondering if i have to create a 100 activities for this manually :( or can i turn them and show the next picture in the same activity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Activity is enough.

Take a look at the Gallery Widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

http://www.anddev.org/a_androidwidgetgallery_-_example-t332.html

Comment: the gallery wont let me change the size to the images. I would like to show them in the whole screen and still be able to curl or turn them to see one by one with only one activity